# Primitive of non $L^1$ function is continuous

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, monotone-functions

I'm beginning with Lebesgue integration this semestre and still quite confused with it. In my course notes, the Lebesgue integration is defined on all measurable functions $R^d \to C$ (infinite integrations are accepted). A function is *integrable* if $\int |f|$ is finite. The set of all integrable functions in $R^d$ is denoted by $L^{1}(R^d)$.

There is an exercice in the notes is to prove that the function $g: x \mapsto \int_{a}^{x} f dt$ where $f \in L^{1}(R^d)$ is continous.

But I can prove that even if $f \notin L^{1}$, it **only needs to be measurable**, then $g$ is continuous. Actually,
$$
|g(t+h) - g(t)| = |\int_{t}^{t+h} f dx| \leq \int (1_{[t,t+h]} \times |f|) dx
$$
Let's consider the monotone sequence of functions $f_{n} = 1_{[t,t+\frac{1}{n}]} \times |f|$ which point-wise converges to $1_{[t,t]} \times |f|$, note that $\int f_{n} dx= \int_{t}^{t+\frac{1}{n}} |f| dx $. Applying the Beppo-Levi theorem:
$$
lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_{n} dx = \int lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n} 
$$
or
$$
lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{t}^{t+\frac{1}{n}} |f| dx= \int_{t}^{t} |f| dx = 0
$$

then $g(t)$ is continuous for any $t$.

Of course this proof cannot be correct since a counter-example is $f = \frac{1}{x}$ which is not continous at $0$, but I still cannot find where is the error (is the Beppo-Levi theorem applicable for finite integration only?)

Comment: When you apply monotone convergence for a *decreasing* sequence, you need some integrability.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't know that. Could you please put this comment into the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You simply forgot to look at the statement of [Beppo Levi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_lemma). Think of the integrals of the decreasing sequence $f_n={\bf 1}_{[n,+\infty)}\to0.$ Anyway, if $f$ is not integrable, $g$ is not even defined. I strongly doubt you were taught "the Lebesgue integration is defined on all measurable functions $\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb C$". Moreover, what would $\int_a^x$ mean for a function on $\Bbb R^d$ if $d\ne1?$

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you. My course notes suggests that the Lebesgue integration in R^d exists for almost all functions (so infinite values are accepted. A function is integrable if the Lebesgue integration of function's module on R^d is finite, it does not require that the Lebesgue integration in a subset of R^d is finite (so g can still be defined)

Comment: @AnneBauval My course notes says (in French): "Il existe un ensemble universellement stable M de fonctions à valeurs dans R dites mesurables contenant C0(Rd) et {1O : O ouvert} et muni d’une unique application
appelée l’intégrale de Lebesgue définie sur l’ensemble"

Comment: With a remark "Attention, la terminologie est un peu trompeuse : les fonctions mesurables positives ont une intégrale bien définie mais ne sont pas toujours
“intégrables” car leur intégrale peut être infinie."

Comment: "A [measurable] function is integrable if the Lebesgue integration of function's module on R^d is finite" Exactly! So: not every mesurable function is integrable. Your "the Lebesgue integration is defined on all measurable functions $\Bbb R^d→\Bbb C$
" is false. And "A function is integrable if the Lebesgue integration of function's module on R^d is finite, it does not require that the Lebesgue integration in a subset of R^d is finite" is contradictory. If $\int|f|d\lambda_d<\infty$ then $\int_Afd\lambda_d$ is finite for every (measurable) $A.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also think in the measure $\phi(E) = \int_E |f| dx$ and consider the decreasing measurable sets $E_n = [t,t+1/n]$ as you defined them. Of course the intersection of all of them is $\{t\}$, therfore $$0 = \int_t^t |f| = \phi(\{t\})=\phi(\cap E_i) = lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \phi(E_i)$$ The last equality is true if $\phi(E_1)$ is finite (or it is finite for some $i$), there is when we had into account the integrability of $f$, otherwise the equality may fails.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the reasoning is Beppo-Levi's theorem (AKA monotone convergence theorem) is more restrictive when applied to decreasing rather than increasing sequences. In the decreasing case, one has to assume that one (and hence every) $f_n$ is integrable. (See the corollary [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Monotone_Convergence_Theorem_(Measure_Theory)), for instance.)

Another vivid illustration of the same issue is with the decreasing sequence of indicator functions
$$f_n=\chi_{[-1/n,1/n]\times\mathbb R}:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$$
which converge to zero pointwise.